# What is the Azure Functions equivalent for services.AddMvc().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions ? If doesn't exist, what approach has to be taken?

Tags: validation, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Azure Functions, please help!

I have the following code in my WebAPI to validate each of the parameters passed and throw the corresponding errors for each of the parameters. The error is thrown even before the control enters the Controller, I want something similar in my Azure Function.

Below is the WebAPI code.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//other code here

services.AddMvc()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        {
            return this.CustomErrorResponse(actionContext);
        };
    });

//other code here
}

private BadRequestObjectResult CustomErrorResponse(ActionContext actionContext)
{
    ////BadRequestObjectResult is class found Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and is inherited from ObjectResult.
    return new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState
     .Where(modelError => modelError.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
     .Select(modelError => new Error
     {
         ErrorField = modelError.Key,
         StatusCode = 400,
         ErrorDescription = modelError.Value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage
     }).ToList());
}
```

**I tried to use the same code in Azure Functions but it doesn't work, seems like the ConfigureApibehaviorOptions is not even triggered. I tried to google a lot and a lot of StackOverFlow but didn't find the suitable answer, hence asking this question.**

Am I supposed to used any custom Filters for this? If yes, how exactly?

Comment: As far as I know so far, there is no option like this for azure functions. Functions run very differently from your standard aspnet application. You would have to validate and return errors on each endpoint on your function app

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Azure Functions equivalent for services.AddMvc().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions ? If doesn't exist, what approach has to be taken?

I do agree with @Nate1zn, There is no option like this in azure functions, but you can validate and create a custom response like below:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp111
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {

            if (req.Body == null || req.Body.Length == 0)
            {
                var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                response.WriteString("Hello Rithwik, Request body is required !!!");
                return response;
            }

            string rithrequest = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            RithwikModel con = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RithwikModel>(rithrequest);
            var rithresults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var context = new ValidationContext(con, null, null);

            if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(con, context, rithresults, true))
            {
                ;
                var response1 = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                var ritherror = new { ErrorField = "queryParameter", StatusCode = 400, ErrorDescription = rithresults };
                var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ritherror); 
                response1.WriteString(x);
                return response1;
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var response2 = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response2.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response2;
        }
    }
    public class RithwikModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Parameter Id is required")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

If  incorrect body:

[image]

If given correct parameters:

[image]